# Batch History Download in Guidewire

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I have a question regarding the download batch history button that can be accessed on the batch info screen by hitting ALT + SHIFT + T. Once you download the history and open the index.html it displays a table with all the results. Is there a way to add a new column to this table? This is OOTB functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to configure this. The current logic is OOTB and comes from internal package `com.guidewire.pl.system.batchprocessing.BatchInfoHelper`. You cannot make any modifications directly in this.

however, if it is extremely crucial that you need this capability, you will either have to redesign custom pcfs or design your own method and export functionality for the action property of the 'Complete Download' button to replace `BatchInfoHelper.download()`.

Given that all this information is available in the database anyway, you could utilize the same or even add a custom export button to query the database and display the findings in an LV or export it.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+shift+T is showing some screenshot option . Its not navigating to the Batch sreen

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the advanced keyboard setting--> Input language hotkeys-->Change key sequence-->Select Not Assigned on both sides.

After that click on Apply then Ok, and restart your PC